# Floating Action Button and View Pager

Tags: java, android, android-studio, floating-action-button

ViewPager is superimposed on top of fab. How to put fab above all?

xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:contextClickable="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/personal_tasks_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#deFFFFFF"
        app:tabTextColor="#81ffffff"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/personal_tasks_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Or maybe that's not the reason? Just the button is not pressed, but the tabs are turned over, when I'm on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CoordinatorLayout` is like a super `FrameLayout`, so if you put a `FAB` on the top and then you add a `ViewPager`, the `ViewPager` will cover / superimpose the previous View. What you can try is to move your FAB to the bottom.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:contextClickable="true">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/personal_tasks_tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#deFFFFFF"
    app:tabTextColor="#81ffffff"
    app:tabGravity="fill" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/personal_tasks_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can also try to anchor the `FAB` to your `ViewPager`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/personal_tasks_viewpager"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```